# ¿Porque no se para la música? AudioClip.stop()

Tags: java

estoy intentando crear un botón para pausar la música, pero no me funciona, el botón de de reproducir si funciona. ¿Alguien me ayuda?. Gracias.

```
package javaSwing;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AudioClip;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Reproducir extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public JButton Reproducir, Pausa;

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Reproducir frame = new Reproducir();
        frame.setBounds(0, 0, 300, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);

    }

    public Reproducir() {

        setLayout(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Reproducir = new JButton("Reproducir");
        Reproducir.setBounds(30, 55, 100, 50);
        Reproducir.setFocusPainted(false);
        add(Reproducir);
        Reproducir.addActionListener(this);

        Pausa = new JButton("Pausa");
        Pausa.setBounds(155, 55, 100, 50);
        Pausa.setFocusPainted(false);
        add(Pausa);
        Pausa.addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        AudioClip audio;
        audio = Applet.newAudioClip(getClass().getResource("/*MUSICA*/"));

        if (e.getSource() == Reproducir) {
            audio.play();
        }
        if(e.getSource() == Pausa){
            audio.stop();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: ¿Salta alguna excepción al hacer clic en el botón `Pausa`?

Comment: @smt no salta ninguna excepción, al hacer clic al botón Pausa no hace nada.

Comment: Y el botón `Reproducir` sí que reproduce audio? Es que estoy probando yo el código en mi PC y no me reproduce nada tampoco. Sí que entra a los `if`, pero no reproduce/detiene nada.

Comment: @smt lo he hecho con netbeans, y solo funciona con .wav. Cree un paquete "musica" y luego copie el archivo .wav y lo puse dentro del paquete. En donde pone /*MUSICA*/, hay que poner "/nombrePaquete/nombremusica.wav"

Comment: Con un fichero `.wav` sí que me funcionan ambos botones sin problema. Realizan el `start` y `stop` perfectamente. Curiosamente, la primera vez que pulso `stop`, el botón no funciona, pero a partir de la segunda sin problemas.

Comment: @smt Te ha funcionado el boton stop? a mi me sigue sin ir :(

Comment: Ojo que a partir de `Java 9` la clase `AudioClip` está `Deprecated`. Más info [aquí](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/applet/AudioClip.html). Puedes usar `MediaPlayer` de `JavaFX`, compatible con `.mp3` y `.wav`. Aquí hay un ejemplo de cómo: [Ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045384/playing-mp3-and-wav-in-java)

Comment: @smt me sigue sin ir de ninguna forma... tienes otra forma de programar el stop?